# python : I have a list in which there are comma separated elements, and I want to get the unique ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['B-album',
 'B-album,B-album,I-album',
 'B-album,B-album,I-album,I-album',
 'B-album,B-album,I-album,I-album,I-album',
 'B-album,B-album,I-album,I-album,I-album,I-album,I-album,I-album,I-album,I-album,O',
 'B-album,B-album,I-album,I-album,O',
 'B-album,B-album,I-album,O',
 'B-album,B-artist',
 'B-album,B-artist,B-playmode']
```

and I only want the unique elements in a list. I would be grateful, if any one can help me
thank you in advance

I have tried `set()`, and `split()` but they did not help much.

what I want is to get rid of repeated words.

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (list(set(','.join(data).split(','))))
```

output:

```
['I-album', 'O', 'B-album', 'B-artist', 'B-playmode']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you're welcome. I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get unique words separated by a comma in each of the strings in the list:

```
r = [','.join(set(s.split(','))) for s in l]

print(r)
```

Output:

```
['B-album', 'B-album,I-album', 'B-album,I-album', 'B-album,I-album', 'O,B-album,I-album','O,B-album,I-album', 'O,B-album,I-album', 'B-artist,B-album', 'B-artist,B-album,B-playmode']
```

And to remove duplicate strings from the new list you can use `set()` again with the new list:

```
r = list(set(r))

print(r)
```

Output:

```
['B-album', 'I-album,B-album', 'B-artist,B-album', 'I-album,O,B-album', 'B-playmode,B-artist,B-album']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help